# What is the difference between $(()) and expr?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, terminal, expr

What is the main difference between `$(())` and `expr` in Unix-Like systems?

Comment: @andlrc That isn't relevant at all.

Comment: `$(())` is for bash arithmetic. expr is for evaluating expressions, this can be arithmetic or strings. Looking in the bash man page for `$(())` and the `expr` man page will tell you everything both commands can do.

Comment: Not just bash arithmetic. `$(( ))` has been in the POSIX sh spec since it was published in 1991.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(())` will almost certainly be within the shell that you are using.
`expr` may be an external call

Comment: Both are specified by POSIX. You might be able to construct a scenario where it is useful to use a command rather than built-in syntax for arithmetic, but by and large `$((...))` has replaced `expr` for all but regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

`expr` is a holdover from the early days of the Bourne shell.  You should avoid `expr` unless you are forced to create scripts which need to be interoperable with legacy (pre-POSIX) `sh` implementations.  (It's not too long ago since Solaris `sh` fell into this category, for example.)